# Find Laurent series of function $f(z) =(1-\frac{1} {z})^3$ around $ z_{0} =i$ on area that contains $2+i$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Find Laurent series of function $f(z) =(1-\frac{1} {z} )^3$ around $ z_{0} =i$ on area that contains $2+i$.

I tried by expanding the function and looking at the Laurent series of $\frac{1} {z} $ around $ z_{0} =i$ and $\frac{-1} {z^2} $ as the derivative of $\frac{1} {z} $ and the same for $\frac{-1} {z^3} $.  Is this correct?

Comment: I hope I'm not misleading you, but I don't think that an area like you need exists: A disc $D(i,r)$ with $r>2$ contains $0$ in it, but $f$ doesn't defined at $0$.

Comment: @J.Doe: True, a disc won't do the trick. Fortunately, a Laurent series can be defined on an annulus, instead of a disc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$0$ is singularity, thus there is no Laurent series uniformly defined on $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{i\}$, of course. (I am not sure if you know this, but I write this for the comment by J.Doe)

Then, is there no answer? Actually we have. Consider $\mathbb{C}\setminus\overline{N(i,1)}$ to avoid the singularity.

Then, we have very natural Laurent series for $1/z$ :

$$\frac{1}{z}=\frac{1}{z-i}+\frac{(-i)}{(z-i)^2}+\frac{(-i)^2}{(z-i)^3}+...$$

The rest is straightforward; what you said in the question is a correct approach.

(If you solved this way and asked for proof-verification, I would say you did well!)